# MySQL: converting date formats inside of strings

Tags: mysql, date

I have a list of file paths and dates stored in a database:

```
               path          |   date
_____________________________|___________
C:\folder\file1 %Y-%m-%d.csv | 2016-09-14
C:\folder\file2_%M %d %Y.csv | 2016-09-13
C:\folder\file3 %y%m%d.csv   | 2016-08-31
```

The dates in the file paths are according to the `STR_TO_DATE` format convention.
The dates will change everyday. 
I need to write a SELECT query that will return:

```
               result 
_________________________________
C:\folder\file1 2016-09-14.csv 
C:\folder\file2_Sep 14 2016.csv 
C:\folder\file3 160831.csv
```

I don't want to end up writing a never-ending `REPLACE` query with all the possible scenarios:

```
REPLACE(... REPLACE(REPLACE(path,'%Y',YEAR(date)),'%d',DAY(date))...)
```

Is there a way to do this with a MySQL built-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) here.  It should replace format strings it recognizes with their values and ignore everything else.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, path) AS result;
```

<sub>NOTE: `%M` Will give the full month ("September"), for the abbreviated month ("Sept") use `%b`.</sub>

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77b6f7/1